# About Extjs & Sencha Touch. How to get data in Store when define a container?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, store

I'm new to Sencha Touch 2, and have difficulty managing the data in Store.
This is my Store and model.

```
Ext.define("Evt", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Model",
    config : {
        fields : ['evt_name','evt_start_time','gln_name'],
    },
});

Ext.define('Evts', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    config : {
        model : 'Evt',
        autoLoad:true,
        proxy : {
            type:'ajax',
            url:'eventslist.json'
        }
    },
});

var store = new Evts();
```

Then I want to use the data in store when define a Container.

```
Ext.define("EvtsList",{
    extend : "Ext.Container",
    requires : "Ext.dataview.List",
    config : { 
        layout : {
        type : 'vbox',
        },
        items : [
            {  xtype : 'titlebar',
               title : "", // To use data 'evt_name' here
               id:'itemTitle',
               docked : "top",
               ui : "dark",
            }
        ],
    },
});
```

I know that using XTemplate and Ext.data.Store can get data loaded by the proxy in the dataview, but how to get the data in other types such as titlebar?
And how to take out those data in the store to an Object so that I can use methods such as get()?
I think I've expressed it clearly? Sorry I'm Not good at English :)

Comment: console.log(record); and see what it is printing.. did you followed exactly as i posted ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to set `evt_name` value of first record from the `store`.

```
Ext.define("EvtsList",{
    extend : "Ext.Container",
    requires : "Ext.dataview.List",
    config : { 
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
        },
        items : [
            {  xtype : 'titlebar',
             title : '', 
             id:'itemTitle',
             docked : "top",
             ui : "dark",
            }
        ],
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.callParent(arguments);
         //data will be passed from Ext.create
         this.down('titlebar').setTitle(this.recordData.evt_name);
    }
});
```

Create store and get the first record

```
var store = new Evts();   //Create store

store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
     var record = records[0]; //Get the first record        
      var data = record.getData(); //Get the data from the record 

      //Create `EvtsList` view and pass the data as config
       Ext.create('EvtsList', {recordData:data}); 

    },
    scope: this
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is an error: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined. I use Sencha touch 2.2.1, sencha-touch-all-debug.js. Should I change it to Extjs?

Comment: @SidneyFan console.log(record); and see what it is printing.. did you followed exactly as i posted ?

Comment: It is undefined. I think the problem is AJAX. The proxy should be loaded before getAt(0)

Comment: how can I load() before getAt() method? I found out that getAt works after load. I put it in the Store, load:{ var record = store.getAt(0) }, and it works.

Comment: There is another error: the data is not defined. The initialize function cannot recognize data.evt_name when Ext.define the Store. I believe that Ext.define runs before the ajax load().

Comment: :( not defined. I haven't make app.js to MVC style and all codes are in the same js file. Is that the reason?

Comment: @SidneyFan create sencha fiddle and post the link here

Comment: @SidneyFan this code works for me http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/c1Cyx/ and it won't run in fiddle.. try in your system

Comment: still not working.. recordData is undefined.. thanks for your help, and I decide to use get() and setTitle() in load() function.. time is limited and I have to continue :(